# Tesseract for License Plate (especially Korean version)

Tags: opencv, tesseract, tess-two

I'm working on my project for License Plate Recognition using OpenCV & Tesseract.
I use OpenCV to change original image to processed image so that Tesseract can read it well.
For example)

Original Image
[image]

Processed Image
[image]

But the result shows "38다9502"and it recognized 3 to 5.
These situation happens frequently especially when the number is 3 or 5.
Is there any suggestion or solution for it??

Answer (score 1):

You can try retraining tesseract with some of your own data. It looks like a good candidate for simply fine-tuning the model. You may not even need much data, just give it several examples of the digits it is having trouble with.

Instructions for retraining are here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00

Answer (score 0):

1)First it can be done with few image processing techniques which is mentioned in this link(https://cvisiondemy.com/license-plate-detection-with-opencv-and-python/)

2)Next if it doesn't show any improvement you can try image thresholding which you can go through in this link(https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

3)If above steps didn't work ,then try to enlarge your image size.

Comment: Link to the tutorial is now https://lucians.dev/license-plate-detection-with-opencv-and-python

Answer (score 0):

I solved this question with using multiple models supported by Tesseract.
With Hangul model, I only received accurate information of Hangul word, not Numbers.
However, with English model, I can received accurate information of Numbers.
So I used these models in parallel and it resulted 99% accuracy of LPR.